# how to $watch currentUser service for changes in my nav controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a have navbar with a "nav" controller, which displays the current user's image. However, i'm not able to get  the nav image to change if the user updates their profile photo.

here is my service:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('clientApp').factory('Account', function ($http, toastr) {
  var currentUser = null;
  function getUser(callback, user) {
    console.log('get user user ', user)
    // if the user has already been retrieved then do not do it again, just return the retrieved instance
    if (currentUser !== null && currentUser !== user) {
      callback(currentUser);
    }
    if (currentUser === null) {
      // retrieve the currentUser and set it as a property on the service
      $http.get('/api/me').then(function (res) {
        // set the result to a field on the service
        currentUser = res.data;
        // call the callback with the retrieved user
        callback(currentUser);
      });
    }
  }

  //updates the currentUser variable
  function updateProfile(profileData, callback) {
    console.log('profile data ', profileData);
    $http.put('/api/me', profileData).then(function (res) {
      currentUser = res.data;
      callback(currentUser);
    }).catch(function (response) {
      if (response.data.message.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.message.length; i++) {
          toastr.error(response.data.message[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return {
    getUser: getUser,
    updateProfile: updateProfile
  };
});
```

watcher in nav controller:

```
  $scope.user = {};

  //watches for currentUser changes in account service
  $scope.$watch(Account.getUser(function(user){}, $scope.user), function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('user update watch', newValue)
      $scope.user = newValue;
  });
```

I'm obviously confusing something here. I'm reviewing information on $watch, but this is not working as I expected. Perhaps because Account.getUser doesn't return anything for the $watch to compare, and instead uses a callback..

If anyone could point where i'm going wrong -- much appreciated.

Comment: @NoobSter BTW, why are you using callbacks and not simply utilizing the promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one you are not using `$watch` quite right, you don't need to pass in callback functions because you can always return promises to the caller.

Consider following example where `NavCtrl` listens to changes in `currentUser`, which is kept, and shared among controllers, in your `userService`. `MainCtrl` is where you call the service to fetch the user (mimicking login or similar).

When user is not known or is not changed, you can return user information from service using `$q` or when it needs to update, using `$http`. These both return promises.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <!-- nav bar -->
  <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    Nav
    <div ng-bind="user.name"></div>      
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- content -->
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Main
    <div ng-bind="'User cached: ' + !!isCached"></div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="getUser()" value="Get">
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, userService) {
  var unwatch = $scope.$watch(function() {
    return userService.currentUser;
  }, function(user) {
    $scope.user = user || { name: 'No user' };
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', unwatch);
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, userService) {
  $scope.getUser = function() {
    var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // 1...10
    userService.getUser(id).then(function(user) {
      $scope.isCached = user.cached;
    });
  };
})

.factory('userService', function($q, $http) {
  var userService = {
    currentUser: null,
    getUser: function(id) {
      if (userService.currentUser && userService.currentUser.id === id) {
        userService.currentUser.cached = true;
        return $q.when(userService.currentUser); 
      } else {
        var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id;
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
          userService.currentUser = response.data;
          return userService.currentUser;
        })
      }
    }
  };

  return userService;
});
```

[image: imgur]

---

Related plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/DzfAtI

Comment: Thanks, Mikko. Quick question though. What is the benefit of invoking the $watch on $destroy?

Comment: It makes sure watcher functions are properly unregistered when scope is disposed/destroyed. Before I trusted Angular to do it for me automatically but seems it's not working 100% of the time as one would think (leaks memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using a instance variable in the service,

When you update the `currentUser` variable in the service after the `update api`, since you are storing it in `currentUser` in a global variable, you can send that as a response of service.

**I have done this without using either `watch` or `rootscope`, please find the code below, also run the snippet**

Here is the code based on the code from @Mikko,

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, userService) {
  $scope.getUser = function() {
    var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // 1...10
    userService.getUser(id).then(function(user) {
      console.log('user',user);
      $scope.user = user;
    });
  };

})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, userService) {
  
})

.factory('userService', function($q, $http) {
  var userService = {
    currentUser: null,
    getUser: function(id) {
      if (userService.currentUser && userService.currentUser.id === id) {
        userService.currentUser.cached = true;
        return $q.when(userService.currentUser);
      } else {
        var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id;
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
          userService.currentUser = response.data;
          console.log(userService.currentUser);
          return userService.currentUser;
        })
      }
    }
  };

  return userService;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      From navigation controller.
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" ng-click="getUser()" value="Get">
      <br><br>
      User Details:
      <br><br>
      <div ng-bind="user"></div>      
      <br><br>
      Name:
      
      <div ng-bind="user.name"></div>      
    </div>
    <br>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

[**Here is the working demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2yI87MLwo6kmXSyDLaMZ?p=preview)

Comment: While this might work I think the main issue here is how to keep separate navigation up-to-date with changing user information.

Comment: did n't get you? `separate navigation up-to-date??`, from my code, as soon as the update methods is called, in the call back we are updating user object using the instance variable from service, so even we are not using `watch`, there by speeding the applicaiton.

Comment: With given implementation I don't think `$scope.user` will be updated if service variable is changed from some other controller nor I don't think navigation controller is the place you'd want to call e.g. `updateProfile`. Care to add a plunker to go with this solution?

Comment: @MikkoViitala, please check my updated answer, created a fiddle taking help from your code.

Comment: @NoobSter, check my latest answer and demo, I created without using either `watch` or `rootscope`

Comment: Now, navigation is usually common for most of the states in single page application. It should not contain single call to userService as you have done but listen for changes to it, because now it will only be called once and NavCtrl scope variable is not affected if some other, like MainCtrl, changes the user information. OP wanted the user profile picture etc. to be reflected to navigation when ever information is changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$rootScope` instead of `$watch`.

In that way you can update it from any controller.