# $watch not detecting changes in service variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to angularjs and I am facing this strange problem where $watch is not firing on change of a variable in service. I don't know where I have made a mistake.

Plunkr: [Link to Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/raPVSED356uqIh4dH9Br)

script.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory("loggedInUser", [loggedInUser]);

function loggedInUser() {
  var currentLoggedInUser = undefined;
  setTimeout(function() {
    currentLoggedInUser = "Karthik";
    console.log("Updated user name");
  }, 3000);
  return {
    getLoggedInUser: function() {
      return currentLoggedInUser;
    }
  };
}

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "loggedInUser", ctrl]);

function ctrl($scope, loggedInUser) {
  var vm = this;
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
  }, function() {
    vm.loggedInUserName = loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
    console.log("Inside Watch");
  },true);
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1 ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
      Hello <span ng-bind="vm.loggedInUserName"></span>
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you watching? You have to give it a variable to actually watch... I.e., $scope.$watch('some.variable', (old-val, new-val) => { do_something(); }

Comment: @rrd I am watching for changes in the variable `currentLoggedInUser`.

Comment: I just recently answered a question like this, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41693955/1061668

Comment: Ok so $scope.$watch('currentLoggedInUser', (old, new) => { }); Then put some console.logs inside there for old/new, then in your code change the variable and see if the $watch fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $timeout instead of setTimeout ? .. cause it need$scope.$apply (outside angular event) .. $timeout is a angular wrapping for setTimeout .. something like:

```
 // Code goes here

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory("loggedInUser", ["$timeout", loggedInUser]);

function loggedInUser($timeout) {
  var currentLoggedInUser;
   $timeout(function() {
    currentLoggedInUser = "Karthik";
    console.log("Updated user name");
  }, 3000);
  return {
    getLoggedInUser: function() {

      return currentLoggedInUser;
    }
  };
}

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "loggedInUser", ctrl]);

function ctrl($scope, loggedInUser) {
  var vm = this;
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
  }, function() {
    vm.loggedInUserName = loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
    console.log("Inside Watch");
  },true);
}
```

BUT .. IF YOU WANT TO USE instead SetTimeout function:

```
  // Code goes here

var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory("loggedInUser", ["$rootScope",loggedInUser]);

function loggedInUser($rootScope) {
  var currentLoggedInUser = undefined;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
    currentLoggedInUser = "Karthik";
    console.log("Updated user name");
    });
  }, 3000);
  return {
    getLoggedInUser: function() {
      return currentLoggedInUser;
    }
  };
}

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "loggedInUser", ctrl]);

function ctrl($scope, loggedInUser) {
  var vm = this;
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
  }, function() {
    vm.loggedInUserName = loggedInUser.getLoggedInUser();
    console.log("Inside Watch");
  },true);
}
```

Comment: It is working!! Can you please explain why $timeout is working ?

Comment: i explain it in the description... cause SetTimeout is a javascript event (outside angular ) .. so it need a $scope.$apply() to works.. but $timeout is already a SetTimeout with $scope.$apply() applied .. it's  a wrapping

Comment: can you show how to use setTimeout and $scope.$apply instead of using $timeout ?

Comment: I use $rootScope cause in the factory i can't inject $scope