# How $watch changes of a variable in a service from component's controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have been through all related topics on SO, namely these two:

[$watch not detecting changes in service variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720133/watch-not-detecting-changes-in-service-variable)

[$watch not detecting changes in service variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720133/watch-not-detecting-changes-in-service-variable)

are tackling the same issue, but i failed to make it working. Unlike in the above cases, I am using a controller from a component, hence maybe this is related to lacking binding in components, idk. Hope for some experinced assistance.

Have a service:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('Test')
        .service('ShareData', ShareData);

    ShareData.$inject = [];

    function ShareData() {
        let vm = this;

        vm.indexes = [];

        vm.setIndexes = function(firstIndexParam, lastIndexParam, message) {
            if (leaderIndexParam !== undefined || partnerIndexParam !== undefined) {
                vm.indexes.mainIndex = firstIndexParam;
                vm.indexes.secondaryIndex = lastIndexParam;
                vm.indexes.message = message;
            }
        };

        vm.getIndexes = function() {
            return vm.indexes;
        };
    }
})(angular);
```

It is used in 3 components. Two of them are sending data into the service, the third one uses this data. Sending of data is accomplished in the following way, works:

```
ShareData.setIndexes(firstIndex, secondIndex, 'update_indexes');
```

Now here is my problem. In main parent controller i can comfortably access the data by

```
ShareData.getIndexes();
```

But my issue is that I need changes in indexes to trigger certain actions in parent controller, so I tried so do as stipulated by relevant questions here on SO:

```
$scope.$watch('ShareData.getIndexes()', function(newVal) {
   console.log('New indexes arrived', newVal);
});
```

In main controller, I am injecting the service:

```
TabController.$inject = ['ShareData'];
```

and using it like:

```
let indexService = ShareData.getIndexes();
```

As i said, I can get the data when I am explicitly calling the function. The issue is that it needs to be triggered by the service itself.

It does not work regardless of shamanistic ceremonies a made :) Now, obviously, I am missing something. Should I somehow bind this service to the component, and if yes how is it done? Or maybe the solution is totally dysfunctional and impossible to achieve in my circumstances? An advise is appreciated!

UPDATE: I already have a functional solution with the same service working with `$rootScope.$broadcast`, however my aim is to get rid of it and not work with the $rootScope.

Comment: Two links in the beginning are the same. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never actually change the value of `vm.indexes` - it always points to the same array. `setIndexes` only modifies properties of this array. That's why `$watch`, which by default checks for reference equality only, fails to spot the changes.

There are (at least) two ways of solving this: either make `$watch` check the object equality instead, by adding a third param there:

```
$scope.$watch('ShareData.getIndexes()', function(newVal) {
   console.log('New indexes arrived', newVal);
}, true);
```

... or (better, in my opinion) rewrite the `set` function so that it'll create a new instance of `indexes` instead when there's a change:

```
vm.setIndexes = function(firstIndexParam, lastIndexParam, message) {
   if (leaderIndexParam === undefined && partnerIndexParam === undefined) {
     return;  
   }
   vm.indexes = vm.indexes.slice();
   Object.assign(vm.indexes, {
     mainIndex: firstIndexParam, 
     secondaryIndex: lastIndexParam, 
     message: message
   });
 };
```

As a sidenote, simply calling `setIndexes()` does not trigger the digest - and `$watch` listener only checks its expression when digest is triggered.

Comment: As a sidenote, I don't really get the purpose of `getIndexes` function in your code. )

Comment: Hm, you are right, indeed I missed the fact that my setIndex only modifies properties of this array, changed it. Also, changed the watcher to watch  $scope.$watch('ShareData.indexes'). At the moment still no success :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! You shed a bit of light upon my dysfunctional implementation :) Продолжу двигать в этом направлении :)

Comment: Ok, something is definitely not right here. Can you use function as a watch expression `$scope.$watch(() => ShareData.indexes, ...)`, and trace its calls? BTW, when exactly `setIndexes` is called in terms of digest?

Comment: The entire module deals with a list of main organizations and partner organizations. Each of the components deals with adding/removing main/partner orgs. They send data to DB, and need to send data to parent controller so that it updates the front view. ```setIndex``` is called when a main/partner organization is updated, the index data is sent into the service to make it available from parent controller.

Comment: ```$scope.$watch(() => ShareData.indexes, ...)``` is called only once - when the controller is loaded. Looks like it does not care about the changes in the service. Same, I applied your first solution with the third parameters - looks like there are logic issues rather than code issue.

Comment: @ raina77ow I wonder if I shouldn't somehow bind the service as a variable to the parent component's controller, could this be the issue? I tried, though unsuccessfully, and wonder if I should explore that solution more ampler as it looks like parent controller has no clue about this service.

Comment: Thank you man, it works and I know why :) With your assistance, I managed to improve my understanding and solved the problem, the function watcher you advised to apply did the trick.